# Axler exercise 2.A.3

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

This exercise in Axler I am trying to solve is:

> Find a number $t$ such that
> $$ 
> (3,1,4), \; (2,-3,5), \; (5,9,t)
> $$
> is not linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}$.

Axler has not introduced row reduction, so I don't know of the way he intended for me to find the scalars. When I do set up a system and row-reduce, I get?
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3 & 2 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & -3 & 9 & 0 \\ 
4 & 5 & t & 0 
\end{array}\right) & \rightarrow  \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &0 & 3 &0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -2 + t & 0 
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
I'm not sure at this point whether to pick a value of $t$ or of the free variable $z$. I read off the reduced system:
\begin{align*}
x + 3z & = 0 \\ 
y - 2z & = 0 \\ 
(-2 + t)z & = 0.
\end{align*}
It's most natural to set $z = 1$. When I do that, I get $x = -3$, $y = 2$, and $-2 + t = 0$, so $t = 2$.

Is this the way the problem was intended to be solved, or was there a better strategy? I considered just trying to "zero" out the first two entries, which would've given a system of two equations in three variables I could then solve for the $t$ that results. But that's in effect exactly what I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors $(3,1,4)$, $(2,-3,5)$ and $(5,9,t)$ are linearly dependent in $\Bbb R$ if there are real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $$(5,9,t) = a(3,1,4) + b(2,-3,5) = (3a+2b,a-3b,4a+5b).$$ Equating the first two entries we form the system $$\begin{cases} 3a+2b=5 \\ \,\,\,a-3b = 9 \end{cases}$$ whose solution is $a=3$ and $b=-2$ (we don't need row reduction for this). Therefore $t = 4a+5b = 2$.

Comment: Every step of what you've done makes sense, but why were you able to form a system only with the first and second components? Is the idea that the $t$ at this point is undetermined, and thus a "degree of freedom" that doesn't actually impose any constraints?